# Wordpress theme does not show once I add custom css style

Tags: css, wordpress

I have made my own template by using html, css and js.
Template worked great on my local server. Now I wanted to create Wordpress theme and once I put my custom css file, page is blank. Nothing shows up on the screen, once I remove it I get information on the screen but without custom css it looks bad.

Here is the function I use to import styles and scripts. I am new in wordpress.

ju_dizajn is custom css. It loads it but site is blank.

```
function ju_enqueue() {

    wp_register_style( 'ju_fonts', 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,400italic,600,700|Raleway:300,400,500,600,700|Crete+Round:400italic');
    wp_register_style( 'ju_bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.css');
    wp_register_style( 'ju_dizajn', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/dizajn.css');
    wp_register_style( 'ju_swiper', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/swiper.css');
    wp_register_style( 'ju_dark', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/dark.css');
    wp_register_style( 'ju_font-icons', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/font-icons.css');
    wp_register_style( 'ju_animate', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/animate.css');
    wp_register_style( 'ju_magnific-popup', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/magnific-popup.css');
    wp_register_style( 'ju_responsive', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/responsive.css');

    wp_enqueue_style('ju_fonts');
    wp_enqueue_style('ju_bootstrap');
    wp_enqueue_style('ju_dizajn');
    wp_enqueue_style('ju_swiper');
    wp_enqueue_style('ju_dark');
    wp_enqueue_style('ju_font-icons');
    wp_enqueue_style('ju_animate');
    wp_enqueue_style('ju_magnific-popup');
    wp_enqueue_style('ju_responsive');

    wp_register_script( 'ju_query', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.js');

    wp_register_script( 'ju_plugins', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/plugins.js');

    wp_register_script( 'ju_function', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/functions.js');  

    wp_enqueue_script( 'script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.js', array (), false, true);
    wp_enqueue_script( 'plugins', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/plugins.js', array (), false, true);
    wp_enqueue_script( 'functions', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/functions.js', array (), false, true);


}
```

Comment: if the site is completely blank when it should not be then that probably means your code causes a 500 error. in wp-config.php you can set a value called wp_debug to true and it should give you an error message with what's going wrong

Comment: Thank you, I made a typo error. It work now :)